# Jenkins Pipeline groovy compareTo operator does not work

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I had this code where I want to get the object with the oldest CreateDate in a list of json objects:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

def result = """{
    "Metadata": [
        {
            "Status": "Active", 
            "CreateDate": "2018-08-14T18:59:52Z", 
        }, 
        {
            "Status": "Active", 
            "CreateDate": "2018-05-18T16:11:45Z", 
        }
    ]
}"""

def all = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(result)

def oldest = all.Metadata.min { a, b -> 
        Date.parse("yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:s'Z'", a.CreateDate).getTime() <=> 
        Date.parse("yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:s'Z'", b.CreateDate).getTime() }
print "oldest=" + oldest
```

works fine in Jenkins Script Console. I.e: it prints the output

```
oldest=[Status:Active, CreateDate:2018-05-18T16:11:45Z]
```

But when the same code is run under Pipeline, it prints

```
oldest=1
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

This is Groovy CPS transformer bug. The difference between script console and Jenkins pipeline is that script console executes script in vanilla Groovy environment while Jenkins pipeline is executed with [groovy-cps](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps/). It means that Jenkins pipeline Groovy script gets executed in the Groovy shell that uses CPS transformation - it modifies the code so it supports this continuous passing style.

According to [`CpsDefaultGroovyMethodsTest`](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps/blob/master/lib/src/test/groovy/com/cloudbees/groovy/cps/CpsDefaultGroovyMethodsTest.groovy#L248), groovy-cps supports `collection.min {}` operation, but only when the closure with a single parameter is used. I've created a test case for a closure with two parameters, like:

```groovy
[3,2,5,4,5].min { int a, int b -> a <=> b }
```

and instead of `2` I get `-1` - it looks like the value of `compareTo()` method is being returned and not the actual min value from the given collection.

#### Solution

The easiest solution to bypass this problem is to extract

```groovy
def oldest = all.Metadata.min { a, b -> 
    Date.parse("yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:s'Z'", a.CreateDate).getTime() <=> 
    Date.parse("yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:s'Z'", b.CreateDate).getTime() }
```

to a method annotated with `@NonCPS` - this annotation instructs groovy-cps interpreter to skip CPS transformations and just run this method as is. Below you can find working example:

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

node {
    stage("Test") {
        def result = """{
            "Metadata": [
                {
                    "Status": "Active", 
                    "CreateDate": "2018-08-14T18:59:52Z", 
                }, 
                {
                    "Status": "Active", 
                    "CreateDate": "2018-05-18T16:11:45Z", 
                }
            ]
        }"""

        def all = new JsonSlurper().parseText(result)

        def oldest = getOldest(all)

        println "oldest = ${oldest}"
    }
}

@NonCPS
def getOldest(all) {
    return all.Metadata.min { a, b -> 
                Date.parse("yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:s'Z'", a.CreateDate).getTime() <=> 
                Date.parse("yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:s'Z'", b.CreateDate).getTime() }
}
```

Comment: Is there also a Jenkins issue related to this kind of functionality not working?